# Fail to print field from structure in C

Tags: c, printf, structure

I want to make an dinamically matrix with "number" structure elements.When I try to print "theNumber" the program won't exit from the printf function.It keep providing me zeros from printf.Maybe I did a wrong allocation?Any idea,please?

```
struct number {
    int theNumber;
};

struct table {
    struct number ** mem;
};

unsigned i;

struct table *createInstance(unsigned min) {

//flag1
    struct table * someInstance = (struct table *) malloc(sizeof (struct table));

//flag2
    if (someInstannce == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

//flag3
    someInstannce->mem = (struct number **) malloc((min + 1) * sizeof (struct number **));

//flag4
    for (i = 0; i <= min; i++) {
        someInstannce->mem[i] = (struct table *) calloc(5, sizeof (struct number *) + 1);
    }

//flag5
    for (i = 0; i <= min; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j = 5; j++) {
            printf("%d", someInstannce->mem[i][j].theNumber);
        }
    }

    return someInstance;
}
```

Comment: As this is strictly C, you may not cast the malloc return value.

Comment: You are using `someInstance` and `someInstannce`. Are these typos, or is there another variable somewhere by that name? Is this code "something like" your code, but not *actually* your code?

Comment: @sjsam: casting `void *` to other pointers is allowe3d by the standard. It is discouraged, though.

Comment: Note: With the types used you don't have a 2D array which a matrix typically is.

Comment: Compiler warnings are there to help you avoid programming errors. Every halfway modern compiler will warn. Pay heed to the warnings!

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (j = 0; j = 5; j++)
```

will clamp `j` to `5` and the condition test will be "true" since `5` is non-0. The loop will never end. Try

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
```

I also question

```
someInstannce->mem[i] = (struct table *) calloc(5, sizeof (struct number *) + 1);
```

where you cast to a different type, and request the pointer size, not the struct size. Should the allocation be

```
someInstance->mem[i] = calloc(5, sizeof (struct number) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory for any pointer, some type of content of that pointer, for instance, int *i=malloc (sizeof(int));

Please edit

```
 someInstannce->mem = (struct number **) malloc((min + 1) * sizeof (struct number **));
```

to

```
 someInstannce->mem = (struct number **) malloc((min + 1) * sizeof (struct number *));
```

and

```
 someInstannce->mem[i] = (struct table *) calloc(5, sizeof (struct number *) + 1);
```

to

```
 someInstannce->mem[i] = (struct number *) calloc(5, sizeof (struct number) + 1);
```

The print loop has bad condition, j=5 should be j <5.